# How to copy a selected documents from one library to another?

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I wish to copy documents of one library to another.
Here I am using SharePoint App in which I am providing drop-down lists to select  documents and then clicking on button I am inserting those drop-down list values into one list.

Here I am inserting data into list because, I want to create a new folder in the destination library.

I have two libraries 
1.Source
2.Destination

This Source library will contain many documents those will be listed into App into the various drop-downs and after that, I wish to copy those selected documents into a destination library.
like bellow snaps
[image]

[image]

**NOTE- I'm using SharePoint designer workflow 2010**

Answer (score 1):

This can be done multiple ways.

Via Server object model.

```
SPFile sourceFile = web.GetFile("http://basesmcdev2/sites/tester1/tester2/A0805051340558063824.txt");

sourceFile.CopyTo("http://basesmcdev2/sites/tester1/sub1/shared documents/A000345.txt", true);
```

Via Jquery/SpServices.

```
function copyItem(){
        var itemurl = "<yoursourcrul>"; //CHANGE THIS
        var dst = "<yourdetsinationurl>"; // CHANGETHIS
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetItem",
            Url: itemurl,
            async: false,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                itemstream = $(xData.responseXML).find("Stream").text();
                       console.log(itemstream);
                itemfields = "";
                $(xData.responseXML).find("FieldInformation").each(function(){
                    itemfields+=$(this).get(0).xml;
                });

            }
        });
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "CopyIntoItems",
            SourceUrl: itemurl,
            async: false,
            DestinationUrls: [dst],
            Stream: itemstream,
            Fields:itemfields,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                var error = $(xData.responseXML).find("CopyResult").first().attr("ErrorCode");
                       console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: so i can put this code in my App's files here inside app.js,rigth?

Comment: yes....and call this method, you can modify method to take sourceurl and destinationurl as parameters... and call this method on button click.